# Slider won't work by javascript(possibly innerHTML?)

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I'm trying to work on a simple slider by Javascript.
It would be great if you could give me a little help.
Thank you.

HMTL below

```
        <div class="carousel-container">
            <div class="auto-slide">

                <img src="img/cheetah.png" alt="">

                <img src="img/elephant.png" alt="">

                <img src="img/penguin.png" alt="">

                <img src="img/zebra.png" alt="">

            </div>
        </div>
```

Javascript below

```
// auto
const slideBox = document.querySelector(".auto-slide")
const autoSlideImages = document.querySelectorAll(".auto-slide img");

// counter
let count = 0;

function autoSlide(){
    if(count < autoSlideImages.length - 1){
        count++;
        console.log("hi.");
    }else{
        count = 0;
        console.log("bye");
    }
    slideBox.innerHTML = "<img" + autoSlideImages[count]; + ">";          
}

setInterval("autoSlide()", 1500);
```

Thank you again.

Comment: Please ignore cosole.log(). I just wanted to make sure if that "if" part was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use,

```
slideBox.innerHTML = "<img src='" + autoSlideImages[count].src + "'>";
```

I am sure this will fix your issue!

If you want to do this with the better way you can use my [CODEPEN DEMO](https://codepen.io/hardik-chaudhary/pen/arxKLN)

Comment: Thank you very much.
It worked.
Would you mind to tell me what was the problem here kindly?

Comment: ```autoSlideImages[count]``` is an image object but ```<img/>``` needs to have ```src``` property there and that should be a ```string``` so we can never pass image object to ```src```. In your code you have not given ```src```.

Comment: If my answer helped you, can you please mark it as an answer?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I marked your answer as correct one.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
setInterval("autoSlide()", 1500);
```

to

```
setInterval(autoSlide, 1500);
```